# Chrome extension cleans storage on uninstall

Tags: google-chrome-extension, storage, uninstallation

Is there any way to prevent deleting localStorage and data in sync storage (chrome.storage.sync) when user is uninstalls extension? I need to keep persistant  authorization data (at least for testing)

Comment: The real question is why do you keep uninstalling so often for testing when you can just update the extension (in which case storage remains).

Comment: Zig Mandel, some code should be executed only when extension is running for the first time. When extension is installed user is getting some gift. User may reinstall extension for abusing this feature. It is not so important, but undesirable. This is not for testing only. But i solved this storing cookie on extension website.

Comment: @ZigMandel : Another reason : because extension errors inspector button under chrome extensions is so damn persistent that you don't know if the changes you made still fails or not. Updating the extension doesn't remove that button, you must delete the unpacked and install it again. I'm storing discussions in local storage (PC) to avoid the hassle of recalling some talks via online history, made a nice dom injected search form, a preview of old messages and full featured filtering. I use Json and clipboard/download as text to save my data elsewhere (until Google provide a useful alternative)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **no**. But there's a bug (or feature?): IndexedDB storage is not deleted with your extension data. Probably you can try that.

Comment: Seems the bug has been fixed (at least on Chrome 96) IndexedDB is being erased when the extension is uninstalled.